# Upload xml files in a folder to Mysql using Php using glob and array

Tags: php, mysql, xml, xml-parsing

I have several xml files in a folder on my webserver. I want to

1. look in the folder
2. get xml file names
3. put file names into array
4. loop those names into a mysql query
5. have contents of all xml files inserted into db

```
 $files = glob('*.xml');

foreach($files as $file){
    mysql_query("LOAD DATA INFILE '".$file."' INTO TABLE tablename ROWS IDENTIFIED BY ''");

}
```

I've spent a couple of days looking for an example or tutorial but can't find anything online.

Above is the best I can come up with.

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code but to do that;

1 - XML files MUST be located in MySQL's data folder. Otherwise, you can't use LOAD DATA thing.

2 - PHP script MUST be started by root or same user with MySQL server's. Otherwise, script won't be able to access and process the files.

If you're trying to this on a shared hosting, I can say that, you can't do it because of lots of restrictions.